# Stop Truncation of Labels with Swift in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uilabel

I am a beginner to swift and am trying to create a simple application. I understand the basics of constraints in Xcode and have applied these to the components in the story board view, however, labels which appear to be of full length in the story board view become truncated when I run the application.

Answer (score 2):

Look for [lineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode) property. It looks like this in IB:
 [image: lineBreakMode property]

Answer (score 0):

set the auto Shrink property in the Attributes inspector , to minimum font scale instead of Fized Size